# How to return default value for empty nodes on XML using Linq

Tags: xml, linq

I have the following XML structure:

```
<Root>
<Item ItemId="abc" ItemType="cde">
        <Item2 ItemId="abc">
          <Value>MyValue1</Val>
        </Item2>
</Item>
<Item ItemId="abc" ItemType="cde">
        <Item2 ItemId="abc">
          <Value>MyValue1</Val>
          <Item3 ItemId="abc">
            <Value>MyValue2</Val>
          </Item3>
        </Item2>
</Item>
```

What I would like to do is basically retrieve the information of that XML (the XML is actually bigger but it contains just those type of nodes only). To be exact, I am interested in retrieve the information from the node named Value but what I want to do is.

- If the "Item" node contains two "Value" nodes, then retrieve the two of them.
- If the "Item" node contains just one "Value" node, then retrieve it and assign a default value like "empty" for the second one.

If I do something like this:

```
var topValue = xDoc.Descendants("Item2").Elements("Val").Select(val => val.Value).ToArray();
var nestedValue = xDoc.Descendants("Item3").Elements("Val").Select(val => val.Value ).ToArray();
```

then, the result of topValue will have 2 values while the result of nestedValue will have 1 value. I will like to have 2 values for nestedValue too (e.g: {"empty", "MyValue2"} ) so once I iterate through them, they match and the output of Value under Item2 and Value under Item3 are in sync.

The desired output will be like:

topValue = {"MyValue1", "MyValue1"}
nestedValue = {"empty", "MyValue2"}

OR maybe there is a better way to use Linq to achieve that with just one single Linq query?

Any idea how to do it?

Many thanks in advance.
J

Comment: To withdraw your question, delete it; don't edit it to all dashes.  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes how did you roll it back?  When I edit either it does not give me the dropdown or changing the DropDown does not change the version.

Comment: @Trisped, the rollback link can be found in the edit history for those with sufficient privilege (2K rep, I believe).